# PHP one textbox to search multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, search, textbox, multiple-columns

It seems there are similar questions left unanswered, so I have thus far been unsuccessful seeking out an answer to my question.

Presently I have an index page on which I have the following horizontal navigation bar set up:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li><li>|</li>
        <li><a href="insert.html">New Entry</a></li><li>|</li>
        <li><label><p>Search:</p></label></li>
        <li><form action="" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search_text" placeholder="Search"/>
            <input type="button" name="search_button" id="search_button" value="Go"></a>
        </form></li>
    </ul>
```

I have another page called `search.php` on which I wish to be able to use the one search text box on the index page in order to search the *ID*, *Name*, and *Category* columns in a single table in my database. The table contains a total of seven columns. I want text entered in the text box to search the three columns only and display the retrieved information in a table showing all 7 columns of information for each row retrieved along with a delete button in an 8th column (on the page only, not in the database) that will delete the corresponding row.

Similarly, I need an update button alongside the delete button that will list the corresponding column's information on a separate page `update.html`

Right now my biggest issue is making one text box so that it can search any one of the three columns and making it display.

On the search page for the display portion of this, I have the following code:

```
    <table border="1" align="center">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Manufacturer</th>
            <th>store</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
        <?php

        //Loops the $results variable

        foreach ($results as $result) {

            echo str_repeat("\t", 3), '<tr>', "\n",
            str_repeat("\t", 4), '<td>', $result['ID'], '</td>', "\n",
            str_repeat("\t", 4), '<td>', $result['Name'], '</td>', "\n",
            str_repeat("\t", 4), '<td>', $result['description'], '</td>', "\n",
            str_repeat("\t", 4), '<td>', $result['manufacturer'], '</td>', "\n",
            str_repeat("\t", 4), '<td>', $result['store'], '</td>', "\n",
            str_repeat("\t", 4), '<td>', $result['category'], '</td>', "\n",
            str_repeat("\t", 4), '<td>', $result['quantity'], '</td>', "\n",

            str_repeat("\t", 3), '</tr>', "\n";
        }

        ?>
    </table>
```

I'm not exactly sure how to place a delete button in an 8th column for each row, but I have a deleteFunct.php page that can be utilized in conjunction with such a button. I suppose I could somehow create a clickable 'delete' link to work as a button, but I'm unsure as to how to set that up. Right now my primary focus is getting the search bar to work. Further assistance with the delete button is appreciated.

Also, I'm a bit new to PHP.

Comment: there are two approahes to this. 1. have a selectbox to indicate which column to search 2. add a modifier in the search text like `id:123`, or `name:foo123` (similar to what github does)

Comment: You can also use IN clause but it will search on all columns uselessly.